# Is there any way to detect if video can be played on a device?

Tags: android

I've done a deep research on playing videos Android devices and I came to a conclusion that there are some Android devices that can't play videos that were recorded on other Android devices.

Right now I'm firing an intent to play video, but the player says "Sorry, the video cannot be played".

I've been wondering if is there a way to detect that the video can't be played before I fire the intent?

Answer (score 0):

The playback depends on the file formats what the player supports.
So if you your using the decoders built into the Android platform(android default decoders) then it is more specific the version of android OS.  So you can check for the media formats supported depending on the device OS Version and allow to launch if it is supported.

As an application developer, you are free to make use of any media codec that is available on any Android-powered device, including those provided by the Android platform and those that are device-specific. However, it is a best practice to use media encoding profiles that are device-agnostic.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't want to play the video, I want some default player to play the video.

Therefore, I want to know what codec the video uses, and if the device support it. I didn't find a way to get this information

Comment: The only way to find the codec required for video playback is to parse the file. You need a suitable parser for it. Going forward to find the device support media formats, Try getting the thumbnail for the corresponding URI: if bitmap returned is null then it's not decodable -> no supporting codec in the device.

Comment: Well I've been through it and there is thumbnail, and even duration. The video is not playable though.

Comment: Do you observe proper thumbnail, i mean the contents of it.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean - I get the thumbnail from the MediaStore, if that helps

Comment: I believe I get the correct thumbnail, I get a bitmap which is not null - Does this mean that the video is decodable on the device? The player cannot play it.

I'll try a patch - loading the video to a SurfaceView which has "GONE" Visibility and to see if the video can be prepared.

I'm starting to think that there is no propper way to do it without NDK (Which I don't know :( )